# Retrieve specific rows of CSV file containing a particular keyword in Python

Tags: python, csv, bigdata

I am currently trying to extract particular rows that contain certain keyword(s)(e.g. 'battery' etc.) from a large csv file.

I have the following code written but it seems not to work for the filter part.

```
    keywords={'battery'}
    import csv
    import sys
    csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
    invalids=0
    valids=0
    path=r'/Users/hung/Desktop/test.csv'
    with open (path,'r')as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=';')
        for row in reader:
            try:
                print(row[2])
                valids+=1
            except IndexError:
                invalids+=1
            for field in row:
                if field in keywords:
                    print(row)
                    break
    print(('parsed {0} records. ignored {1}').format(valids,invalids))
```

I am getting an error saying 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' for 'print' in the last line.
Is there anything missing causing the error? Or is my code not gonna work?

Thanks.

Comment: Your print statement should not have parenthesis around the format string. `print('parsed {0} records. ignored {1}'.format(valids,invalids))`

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
print(('parsed {0} records. ignored {1}').format(valids,invalids))
```

With

```
print('parsed {0} records. ignored {1}'.format(valids,invalids))
```

See documentation for [string.format](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)